# Outlook: Is it possible to completely hide the number of items in an Inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, inbox, counter

I would like to hide the number of items counter which is displayed after the inbox in the mail folders overview.

I am aware of the possibility to switch the counter from unread emails to total number of email; is there also an option to completely hide this counter?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not such an option in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rule to make all incoming emails as read and put the inbox nr on 'only unread messages'. This should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).